# Move X axis when it's greater than 6 C# Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm having trouble doing this

[image]

What is happening to me is this

[image]

Here's my code

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 6];
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;
int counter = 0;


if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
{
     break;
}
            
if (result.Equals(newPreviousValue) && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
{
     yIndex += 1;
     counter++;
     table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
else
{
      xIndex += 1;
      yIndex = 0;
      counter = 0;
      table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
if (result.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
{
    yIndex += 1;
    table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
     newPreviousValue = result;
     //new position
 if (counter < 6) { 
     bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -19, 0f);
 }
 else
 {
      bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -95, 0f);
 }
```

What I want is that if the newPrevious(which is composed of BLUE,RED AND GREEN) has got a value of BLUE/RED/GREEN and exceeds the value of 6, it will automatically moved one value in the X axis but in the same in row.

Could someone help me please .

## EDIT

I uses the code of Ignacio

```
if (counter > 6)
{
     xIndex2 += 1;
     yIndex2 = 0;
     table[xIndex2, yIndex2] = result;
}

if (counter < 6)
{
    bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -19, 0f);
}
else
{
    int reminder = counter % 6;
    bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3((xIndex2 + reminder) * 19, -95, 0f);
}
```

But it gives me this

[image]

If you look closely it has a prefab that are in the same position sir .

Comment: Ok speaking in coordinates inside your board. For an object located in the following position (x = 8, y = 2), what position would you like to have instead?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre base on picture above . I would like it to form like a letter L if it exceeds to 6

Comment: So you want that those blocks stay in the last row (row 6), but move to the next column (to the right). Isn't?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre yes exactly. I need to move those two block to the right because it exceeded to 6

Comment: ok, and those magic numbers: 19 and 95, you are using them to set the size of the blocks? or what is the meaning they have? By the way, I would recommend you to write them as variables on top of the code so it is easier to understand. Because even for you it may be confusing in the future to know why you set those values.

Comment: What are the blue and red colors supposed to be?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre `bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -19, 0f);` this line of code is for the original position of the blocks . I am setting them . Okay I'll set them as a variable next time sir

Comment: @AustinWBryan those are for my scoring board. `BLUE  = PLAYER1 , RED = PLAYER2, GREEN = TIE;` They are set automatically by a condition

Comment: So it xIndex = 0 and yIndex = 0, you will have a block located in the row 1 and column 1. I will give an answer with this in mind. If I am wrong let me know.

Comment: Yes precisely then i will multiply it by xIndex * 19 and yIndex * -19 to set them into the next position @IgnacioAlorre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the root of the problem is here:

```
if (counter < 6) { 
     bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -19, 0f);
 }
 else
 {
      bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex2 * 19, yIndex2 * -95, 0f);
 }
```

Since you multiply by -95 you are placing it in the first row.

What you should do instead is something like this:

```
if (counter < 6) { 
         bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -19, 0f);
     }
     else
     {
          int reminder = counter % 6;
          bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3((xIndex2 + reminder) * 19, yIndex2 -19, 0f);
     }
```

So basically you will keep placing the block in the last row, which in your case you use the value -19 multiply by the index.

And the reminder will help you to change the column instead, that is to move the blocks in the X axis. So for example 7 % 6 = 1. Then you will add one (1 position to the right) to the block. If 8 % 6 = 2. The you will add two positions to the right...

**Edit:**

It may be because of this part. Is it possible you are already increasing the axis value here? :

```
if (counter > 6)
{
     xIndex2 += 1;
     yIndex2 = 0;
     table[xIndex2, yIndex2] = result;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I am not sure if your first position is when yIndex = 0 or when yIndex = 1. I assume the first one is when yIndex = 1. Let me know if it is when yIndex = 0.

```
if (counter < 6) { 
         bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -19, 0f);
     }
     else
     {
          int reminder = counter % 6;
          bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3((xIndex2 + reminder) * 19, -19, 0f);
     }
```

**Edit 3:**

You will need to remove now this part, since you are adding here an extra +1 to xIndex

```
if (counter > 6)
{
     xIndex2 = 0; //Here you were adding + 1
     yIndex2 = 0;
     table[xIndex2, yIndex2] = result;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out :)

Comment: Ok let me know. I was understanding that with bigroad.transform.localPosition you set the position of the block

Comment: Yes just wait a minute sir :)

Comment: It looks funny sir

Comment: I edit my question sir . Could you please take a look

Comment: Ok, let me try to think. Exactly in what part of the code you assign the position to the block?

Comment: in here sir `bigroad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 19, yIndex * -19, 0f);`

Comment: I removed some of my codes . Could you try to take a look again sir please . Thank you.

Comment: It seems for me you are increasing the yIndex2 somewhere, but it should not increase if yIndex is > 6. But I am not able to spot the exact place in your code. Try with these new edit, just removing the yIndex2 in the case counter > 6.

Comment: Ok, try with the 3rd edit, I feel this will solve the problem once per all

Comment: its getting worst sir . Because some of my prefabs are in one place

Comment: what is the exact problem? Can you add a new image with the current output?

Comment: I edited already my question sir . As you can see on the image some of them are thick red and blue that means it has another prefab on that the same spot .

Comment: So now, there is a gap between the red things? I believe you can fix it with my edit 3.